# Comprehension about definition of dense set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Dense set in Real Analysis, Carothers, 1ed was defined in his homework and captured below:
[image]

1. What's the meaning of empty interior? Examples will be appreciated^_^
2. Can I claim that (0,1) is dense in [0,1]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Empty interior simply means that there is no non-empty open set inside the set. For example $\{1\}$ has empty interior, as does $\mathbb{Q}$, as subsets of the reals.
2. $(0,1)$ is certainly dense in $[0,1]$ since its closure is $[0,1]$.

Comment: So (a),(b),(c),(d) are totally equivalent for A be dense in M?

Comment: Yes, they are all equivalent, so we can take any one of them to be our definition of dense.